# See the whole screen when installing Linux on VMWare vSphere 5.1.0

Tags: linux, resolution, vmware

I'm using VMWare vSphere 5.1.0 on Windows 10 and I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a new virtual machine I just created. All is good, excepted the screen is so tiny I can't see or click the buttons and other menu items in the graphical installlation wizard. The scroll bars that appear don't have any effect, so I can't even scroll right or down. A guess a picture says it all:

[image: Ubuntu install screen]

I have seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/951406/how-to-stretch-a-guest-os-on-vmware) and tried installing VMWare Tools, while I had that install page open. Then I read on [their page](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_running_tools_status.html) about checking the status of VMWare Tools:

> In a Linux or FreeBSD virtual machine, boot the guest operating
>   system, start X and launch your graphical environment. Then you can
>   launch the VMware Tools background application with this command:
>
> vmware-toolbox &

To me this sounded like Linux must already be fully installed and running. The problem is, I want a solution that will help me install it! Any workarounds or solutions?

I looked up how to change the resolution of the install, and saw [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements):

> Screen resolution will be set at the highest your graphics card can
>   handle but when you boot-up you should be given a "Low graphics mode"
>   option which allows you to set it to something better for your
>   monitor.

But I never see an option to change the resolution. Every time I power up the machine, it goes straight to the welcome screen that's very difficult to navigate. Of course, navigating with the keyboard would be an option, but that's tricky if I can't see what I'm selecting! Thank you.

Comment: You won't be able to change the resolution until you install the VMWare Tools.  You might have better lucker with the resolution though with a newer version of Ubuntu.  You likely will encounter a capability problem with the VMWare Tools if you stay on 12.04

Comment: Actually, this isn't specific to the guest OS, a little while back had the exact same issue with CentOS. Turns out it's a Windows 10 compatibility issue with this vSphere version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue once before and I googled around and found [this link.](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/543815?start=0&tstart=0)

> We were able to fix it by disabling the DPI settings in the file properties. To do this, right click on the shortcut and choose Properties (if you don't see this but instead see "open file location," click that and then right click -> "Properties" on the file from windows explorer) From there, go to the Compatibility tab and check "Disable Display Scaling on high DPI settings"

Hopefully this helps somewhat.

Comment: Indeed I'm running Windows 10! Updated the question. So the solution is really simple:


- On Windows 10, right-click on the VMWare Vsphere shortcut and click properties

- Then on the Compatibility tab, tick the "Disable display scaling..." box

I restarted VPshere just to be sure, and it works, thanks!