# How to get fullscreen to work in VMware Player for OSX guest?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have installed OSX High Sierra as guest OS on VMware Player 14 (Host OS - Win 10).

I have successfully installed OSX and installed VMware Tools on it as well.

The only problem I'm facing is -
I am not able to get the VMware Player (or OSX to go full screen i.e., I want it to stretch out to the whole screen with 1920x1080 resolution).

I have done this-

`Display => Auto detect (didn't work)`

So, I did,

`Display => Manual => 1 monitor, 1920x1080 resolution.`

And the display resolution inside of MAC OSX is 1024x768

Is there a way to stretch out the screen with 1080p or atleast a proper 720p resolution?

What am I missing?

I tried looking at some [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1184470/see-the-whole-screen-when-installing-linux-on-vmware-vsphere-5-1-0) already posted here, but, none of them work or they are too old solutions.

Screenshot of how awfully small it looks-

[image: Small screen]

Answer (score 1):

Open a DOS window and type:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS 10.15 Catalina" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution HxV
```

where HxV will be

```
1280x720 | 1920x1080 | 2560x1440 | 2048x1080 | 3840x2160 | 5120x2880 | 1280x800 | 1280x1024 |1600x900 | 1440x900
```

Comment: I doubt VBoxManage, a VirtualBox tool, will work well for a VMWare vm....

Answer (score 0):

In VMware, go to `View > Autosize` and click on `Autofit Guest`. This will make `OSX` occupy the entire space available.

This might sometimes cause some scaling issues. If so, go to `VM > Settings` and select `Display` under `Hardware` and under `Display scaling` uncheck `Automatically adjust user interface size in the virtual machine`

Answer (score 0):

You need install VMware Tools: VM > Install VMware Tools, 
you can reference from: [techsviewer](https://techsviewer.com/how-to-enter-full-screen-mode-on-macos-on-vmware/)

Comment: Why does the link text look like a link to our sibling site [DIY.se] when the actual hyperlink directs somewhere else entirely?

Comment: that's a good point. I have editied it to remove the misleading text.

Comment: The question says that VMware Tools is already installed.